# Filter elements of an ng-repeat list from another ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have only one array which shows title, description and category.
As I don't know the categories (because the users can add their own) I did the categories list with an ng-repeat, same to show the items.
And I need the items to be able to filter with *two* filters: with a **text input** which filters by title (this one works really nice) and with the **categories buttons** (which doesn't work).

Here's how I did the ng-repeat for the categories:

```
<div class="list_categories">
 <!-- I put 'ng-repeat-start' and 'ng-repeat-end' to be able to add the value "checked" to the first input -->
 <!-- it wasn't working and @tbone849 already helped me with that-->
 <label ng-click="clearAll()" ng-repeat-start="x in categories" ng-if="$first">
   <input type="radio" id="optradio" name="optradio" ng-model="searchCategory.Category" value="{{x}}" checked="checked">
   <p>{{x}}</p>
 </label>
 <label ng-click="clearAll()" ng-repeat-end ng-if="!$first">
   <input type="radio" id="optradio" name="optradio" ng-model="searchCategory.Category" value="{{x}}">
   <p>{{x}}</p>
 </label>
</div>
```

And here's the ng-repeat of the items:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="x in items | filter:searcher | filter:searchCategory" >
  <div class="title-space">
    <h2>{{x.Title}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="description-space">
    <p>{{x.Description}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more details of my code I did a working example in [**this Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tG7SEzt6dUnJcqVL?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview).
I hope someone can help me to make the Categories filter to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-checked to handle checking the first option.

```
<label ng-click="clearAll()" ng-repeat="x in categories">
    <input type="radio" id="optradio" ng-model="searchCategory.Category" name="optradio" ng-value="{{x}}"  ng-checked="$first">
   <p>{{x}}</p>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, that really worked.. any idea for the filtering problem which is my main problem?

Comment: Are they able to search by one category or multiple categories?

Comment: Check the Plunker example I did, I did an array with the categories and used that to create de categories list.

Comment: Try changing the filter parameter to searchCategory.category

Comment: I think is already like that, the radio input has `ng-model="searchCategory.category"`

Comment: Try changing it in your filter ng-repeat="x in items | filter:searcher | filter:searchCategory"

Comment: You mean adding .category at the end of the filter like: `filter:searchCategory.Category`? Because it doesn't work, I also tried adding `filter:searchCategory:strict` with no success..